# Do the commendation votes at the end of of a match matter?

Tags: overwatch

At the end of every *Overwatch* match, there are 4 players shown who did things like the most healing, most kills, most time on objective, and stuff like that. I can vote for one of these people.

[image: Commendation screen]

What effect does my vote actually have? Does the recipient of the vote get any sort of bonus for the vote, or for having the most votes? I've won a few times but didn't notice anything special happen.

Comment: I want to say there are achievements related to it... possibly even ones that unlock skins.  I'd have to check.

Comment: I have seen a match with only three players listed at the end, so there must be some threshold to pass in order to get onto the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **What you see is what you get! It's just an opportunity for players in the match to commend each other on good gameplay. :)**
>   <sub>[@PlayOverwatch on Twitter (May 30, 2016)](https://twitter.com/playoverwatch/status/721480094582083585)</sub>

---

Cards can reach "Epic" or "Legendary" status at 5 or 10 votes respectively. The only 'reward' is a unique voice line from the hero on the card. There's a full list of commendation voice lines on the [Overwatch Wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Card#Voice_lines).

In other words, [commendation votes are like clapping](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745056020#post-2). They do not have any long-term tangible impact.

Answer (score 6):

Right now, it's just for the lulz :D

They might add something points related in the future, who knows.